# MacBook Pro (mid-2012) SSD Problems

Tags: macbook-pro

Ok a few months ago I bought a Macbook Pro 2012 and shortly afterwards I installed a Adata 512GB SSD.  I cloned my existing Mechanical drive to the new internal SSD and everything went fine for a few months.  My Mackbook Pro was booting up in about 11 secs and running like a pro.  Well a few weeks ago I started having problems.  Here are the following problems:

1. When I close the laptop and put it to sleep it freezes when I wake it up and it becomes unresponsive to the point that I have to completely turn it off.
2. Sometimes when I have to power it on it has trouble finding the internal SSD and after a few minutes I get the blinking folder with the question mark.  This tells me it's having problems finding my SSD.  Sometimes I have to turn it off and back on a few times or do the clear NVRAM key combination inorder to get it booted up.  Once it's booted up it works just perfect.  but if I let it go to sleep then its back to problem 1 above.

This has become increasingly frustrating as my Macbook it used for editing pictures from my photography sessions and also editing videos.   And I have tried all the different solutions from the internet/google/forums.  Well the other night I decided to open it up and install my old mechanical drive back in it.  When I turned it on the it found the drive and booted right up.  I put it to sleep and it woke back up with no problem and it didn't freeze.  I also powered it off and back on a few times and it booted with no problem.

Is it safe to assume that my Adata SSD is dying or could it be something else that's causing this problem?  I also did a erase and restore from a time machine backup and had the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to work at an Apple certified repair center and would definitely suspect the SSD. Things you could check:

1. Reseat the sata connector on the logic board side
2. Try a different sata cable
3. Try a different ssd
4. Put the ssd in a diffent machine and see what happens

Unfortunately not everyone has multiple ssd, parts and machines to test with. Can you try and claim warranty on the ssd?

Comment: The weak point on those MBPs is the SATA cable. You can get a replacement very cheaply ($15), and it's worth a punt.

Comment: I would think that if it was the sata cable then my old drive wouldn't work.  Yesterday I installed my original drive back in and it is currently running and I haven't had any of the problems mentioned above.   I have rebooted several times and each time it boots up normally.  I also have a USB caddy for sata and SSD drives that I put the SSD in and my Macbook doesn't detect it consistently.  Yesterday I plug it and unplug it several times before it would detect the drive.  But any other drive I put in the caddy detects immediately.  So I believe the SSD is definitely the problem.

Comment: Turns out I have a 3 year warranty on my SSD so I have contacted the company and describe to them the problem.  They exchange it and send me a new one.  Just waiting on them to send my a RMA so I can package it up and send it off.

Comment: any update on how this worked out?